# McKinsey curve in pgfplots (creating continuous cost curves)

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I'm trying to recreate the Mckinsey curve in `pgfplots`:

[image: mckinsey curve]

I'm not sure I understand how to control the `\addplot` with bar graphs completely (how to make each bar graph stand next to each other using `bar width`, `bar shift`, and plot coordinates.

I've included my attempt to start it: I plan to create a continuous bar graph to create a cost curve. So I would define a bar graph closely to each other. In addition, I'm trying to figure out how to add labels with lines for each bar graph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[ybar,axis lines=left,
width=6in,
ymin=-190, ymax=40,
xmin=0, xmax=4200]


\addplot+[ybar interval, range=-190:40l] plot coordinates
{(0,-189.6580431) (100,20) (220,10) (330  ,0 )}
;



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

UPDATED:

I have updated the code above to include one of the comment's suggestions of using `ybar interval`. The last additional piece would be to add bar labels with lines for say x>1.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Thank you! - as suggested, I have turned the image into a link

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can use the `ybar interval` option for such plots. See the manual for pgfplots.

Comment: @percusse, I have updated the code above to include your suggestion - very helpful. a few details I'm battling with is how to shift the x axis to the y=0.

Comment: I can't remember by heart but `axis x line*=middle,axis y line*=left,` shoudl do it. If those keys are not correct then look at the manual there should be an option for `axis x line` or something named similar.

Comment: @percusse, right on the money - to add to that: you can also add `axis on top=true` - I guess I can try and solve this myself and post an answer soon, if no one answers. Comments have been very helpful

Comment: I'm almost there - I have most of the ingredients. I found this command called `nodes near coords` which gives me hope that I can add word labels to some bars. However, this code only gives the y-axis value for each bar. My lasts steps are to put the word labels for select bar graphs - any hints on commands I should explore is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I finally finished the Mckinsey - but I am open to comments in "cleaning" it up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
 extra description/.code={

 \node at (.2,.2) {Bioenergy};
 \node at (.5,.5) {Geothermal};
 \node at (.6,.7) {Wind};
 \node at (.8,.8) {Solar};

}}}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[ybar,axis x line*=middle,axis y line*=left,axis on top=true,
width=6in,xlabel=MtCO2,ylabel=\$/tCO2,title = CDP Mckinsey Carbon Abatement Curve,
ymin=-150, ymax=40,
xmin=0, xmax=3000]


    \addplot+[ybar interval, range=-190:40l] plot coordinates
    {(0,-189.6580431)
(220,-110)
(350,-98)
(1000,-90)
(1400,20)
(1800,24)
(2500,33)

}
    ;

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: mckinseyplot]

Comment: I'm still open to suggestions on how to add lines from the words to the actual bar its referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to suggest "how to add lines from the words to the actual bar its referencing" but, who knows?

Next you'll find two possibilities, one uses `pins` and the second regular `nodes` both placed with `axis cs` coordinate system. From `pgfplots v1.11` prefix `axis cs` is not needed anymore. More details about this kind of annotations in manual section "4.17 Custom Annotations".

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, axis x line*=middle, axis y line*=left,
    axis on top=true, width=6in, xlabel=MtCO2,
    ylabel=\$/tCO2, title = CDP Mckinsey Carbon Abatement Curve,
    ymin=-150, ymax=40, xmin=0, xmax=3000]

\addplot+[ybar interval, range=-190:40l] plot coordinates{%
    (0,-189.6580431) (220,-110)
    (350,-98) (1000,-90) (1400,20)
    (1800,24) (2500,33)
};

\node[coordinate, pin=above:{Solar}] at (axis cs:2200,20) {};
% 
% Next lines don't include prefix `axis cs` because v1.11 is used.
%
\node[coordinate, pin=above:{Wind}] at (1600,20) {};
\draw  (1800,-60) node[below] {Geothermal} -- (1200,-50); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]